# Extract data from a multiline string and store it in python dictionary

Tags: python, regex

The data to be extracted is present in a specific format wherein the **headings** (written in uppercase) are to be stored **in keys** and **text** present under the heading **in values** of a dictionary.

I am attaching a sample text file present in the format.

[image]

The expected output for the following sample will be

```
dict = {"1. PAPER1" : "text under this heading",
        "INTRODUCTION" : "text under this heading",
        "PROBLEM STATEMENT" : "text under this heading",
        .
        .
       }
```

I believe it can be solved using either regular expressions or conditionals. I tried but was not able to solve.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use regex at first, unless you really love regex. Try splitting the data on double newlines, make a loop, gather uppercase things as keys and the following things as values. And don't use `dict` as a name in Python.

Comment: @kwinkunks thanks a lot for editing the question (Please excuse me i am fairly new to this platform.) Your suggestions came really handy while solving the problem. I have added my solution to the answers to this post. THANKS again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem this way.

```
with StringIO(txt) as f:   
    key = []
    temp = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() != '':
            if line.strip()[0].isupper() and line.strip()[1].isupper() :
                list2= line.split(" ")
                print(list2)
                temp = []
                for i in list2:
                    if i.isupper():
                        temp.append(i)
                key.append(' '.join(temp))

import re
split_str = '|'.join(key[1:])
value = re.split(split_str,txt2)

dictionary = dict(zip(key,value))
```

'txt' represents multi-line string containing data.

lists 'key' and 'value' store keys and values for the dictionary respectively.

Thanks a lot everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
txt = """
INTRODUCTION 

Blah blah blah

blah? blah blah

2. NEXT SECTION

Blah Blah? Blah blah blah.
"""
```

Logic:

```
txt_split = [*filter(lambda _: _!='', txt.split('\n'))]

txt_split_filt = [''.join([*filter(str.isalpha, _)]) for _ in txt_split ]

header_inds = [1 if _.isupper() else 0 for _ in txt_split_filt]

res = {}

this_ind = -1
for idx, header_ind in enumerate(headers):
    if header_ind:
        this_ind = idx
        res[txt_split[this_ind]] = ''
    else:
        res[txt_split[this_ind]] += '\n'
        res[txt_split[this_ind]] += txt_split[idx] 


res
```

Output:

```
{'INTRODUCTION ': '\nBlah blah blah\nblah? blah blah',
 '2. NEXT SECTION': '\nBlah Blah? Blah blah blah.'}
```